# Error while creating partial classes with LLBLGenPro

Tags: asp.net-mvc, llblgenpro, data-annotations

I simply am trying to declare partial classes for the tool-generated LLBLGenPro (partial) classes, so that I can use DataAnnotation for validation purposes. However, things don't seem to work here.

Following is how my code looks like :

```
namespace MyApp.DataLayer.EntityClasses
{
    [Serializable]
    public partial class LoginEntity : CommonEntityBase, ISerializable
    {
        .....
    }
}
```

And for DataAnnotations ...

```
namespace MyApp.DataLayer.EntityClasses
{
    [MetadataType(typeof(LoginEntityValidation))]
    public partial class LoginEntity
    {

    }

    public class LoginEntityValidation
    {
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Required !")]
        public string Username { get; set; }
    }
}
```

// This gives me compile time errors "MyApp.DataLayer.EntityClasses.LoginEntity' does not contain a constructor that takes 1 arguments" and so on.

Any idea on how to make this working?

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0):

You should not use your entity classes in views. You should use ViewModel classes and put validation there. For entity->viewmodel conversion you can use [AutoMapper](http://automapper.codeplex.com/)

Comment: Thanks for your reply ! Ok, I have configured the AutoMapper. But how do I make it to validate my core entities? Basically, I want to attach validation attributes to my core entities, so that validation can occur at any place independent of any particular layer. This works fine with EntityFramework, though.

Comment: I think mixing validation and business logic is bad idea. You should apply validation logic to user input that initiates data changes and keep your domain model for business logic